# Kernel panic - not syncing: Vfs unable to mount root - (0,0) on Beagleboard-xm

Tags: linux-kernel, beagleboard

i am facing a problem on my Beagleboard-xm after successfully update a kernel image on to the board when i just booted the board its got stuck at the point where its showing a kernel message....

> **Kernel panic - not syncing: Vfs unable to mount root - (0,0)**

can anybody please explain solution for this or share some experience with me if they have faced same problem as mine and got the solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel cannot find a root device and the boot fails.
The pair at the end of the message explains the reason
of such failure and should have the following meaning:

If the first number is 0 the kernel didn't find any suitable device.
If the second number is 0 the kernel found a suitable device but it
didn't manage to mount the filesystem.

In your case it seems that the kernel misses the driver to access the device.

Try the tips suggested here in the section "Unable to mount root-fs"

http://swift.siphos.be/linux_sea/kernelbuilding.html#idm2877662600400